# Use culture parameter in route to change culture

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

On an Asp.Net 3.1 application I have on Startup the following for localization:

```
  application.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions {
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("pt"),
    SupportedCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("en"), new CultureInfo("pt") },
    SupportedUICultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("en"), new CultureInfo("pt") }
  });

  application.UseEndpoints(x => {
    x.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
  });
```

I am using Attribute Routing on the controllers:

```
[HttpGet("about")]
public IActionResult Index() => View();
```

I am able to see the content in correct culture using:

```
/about?culture=pt
/about?culture=en
```

But I would like to have culture as a route parameter so I updated it to:

```
[HttpGet("{culture?}/about")]
public IActionResult Index() => View();
```

However, the culture does not change when I access:

```
/pt/about
/en/about
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Have u tried configuring `RequestLocalizationOptions` with `options.AddInitialRequestCultureProvider(new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider { RouteDataStringKey = "culture" });`. `RouteDataStringKey`'s default value is `"culture"`, but in case your route parameter is set to something else thats how u wld set it.

Comment: Your suggestion almost work but it breaks attribute routing. The routes start to be controller/action instead of the attribute route I defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, `UseRequestLocalization` supports the following *ordered* [`RequestCultureProviders`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.requestlocalizationoptions.requestcultureproviders?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Builder_RequestLocalizationOptions_RequestCultureProviders):

> 1. QueryStringRequestCultureProvider
> 2. CookieRequestCultureProvider
> 3. AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider

By adding `"{culture?}"` to the `HttpGet` constraint, you've turned it into a route parameter. This is supported, but must be configured. Here's an example:

```
var requestLocalizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions {
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("pt"),
    SupportedCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("en"), new CultureInfo("pt") },
    SupportedUICultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("en"), new CultureInfo("pt") }
};

requestLocalizationOptions.RequestCultureProviders.Add(
    new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider());

application.UseRequestLocalization(requestLocalizationOptions);
```

If you'd like `RouteDataRequestCultureProvider` to be checked first, add it as the *first* provider:

```
requestLocalizationOptions.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(
    0, new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider());
```

The built-in extension method, [`AddInitialRequestCultureProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.requestlocalizationoptionsextensions.addinitialrequestcultureprovider?view=aspnetcore-3.1), uses the same implementation as above. Using that looks like this:

```
requestLocalizationOptions.AddInitialRequestCultureProvider(
    new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider());
```